# `{ ... }` in output from `po` in Xcode debugger indicates what?

Tags: xcode, swift, debugging, swift2

I gather strings (as received as the block's first parameter in a call to [`enumerateTagsInRange:scheme:options:usingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSLinguisticTagger_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLinguisticTagger/enumerateTagsInRange:scheme:options:usingBlock:)) into an array and then inspect the array in the Xcode debugger with `po strings`. Some strings bear the annotation `{ ... }` like so:

```
(lldb) po strings
▿ 3 elements
  - [0] : "Determiner"
  - [1] : "Adjective"
  - [2] : "Adjective" { ... }

(lldb) expr strings
([String]) $R5 = 3 values {
  - [0] : "Determiner"
  - [1] : "Adjective"
  - [2] : "Adjective"
```

What does `{ ... }` indicate? If it is additional information, of what kind is it and can I "expand" it somehow?

Comment: This is just a wild guess: Probably this indicates somehow that this is a interned/pooled string? Are the object references equal?

Comment: @idmean `expr strings[1] == strings[2]` gives `true`. `expr strings[1] === strings[2]` gives `error: binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two String operands`